# VB - Read ChildNode line by line where Name equals

Tags: xml, vb.net, node.js

I am currently stuck with an issue in VB.net using XML. I am trying to grab all of the child nodes from a selected node and return them one by one.

The code is returning the nodes, but it is dumping them all into one message. I am also not able to get it to search by a particular node (Document).

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Documents>
<DocType>
    <Document ID="1">Document Name 1</Document> 
        <Fields>
            <Field Type="Date">Field1</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field2</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field3</Field>
        </Fields>
</DocType>
<DocType>
    <Name ID="2">Document Name 2</Name> 
        <Fields>
            <Field Type="Date">Field1</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field2</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field3</Field>
        </Fields>
</DocType>
<DocType>
    <Name ID="3">Document Name 3</Name>
        <Fields>
            <Field Type="Date">Field1</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field2</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field3</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field4</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field5</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field6</Field>
            <Field Type="TxtBox">Field7</Field>
        </Fields>
</DocType>
</Documents>
```

**VB Code**

```
    Dim sd As New XmlDocument()
    Dim sdXML As New FileStream("xmlFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim sdNode As XmlNodeList
    Dim sdNum As Integer
    Dim sdMSG As String

    sd.Load(sdXML)
    sdNode = sd.GetElementsByTagName("DocType")

    For sdNum = 0 To sdNode.Count - 1
        sdMSG = sdNode(sdNum).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText

        ''Show message box
        MsgBox(sdMSG)

    Next
```

To recap: I am looking to get a message box for each field in a particular document

This is my first time creating / using XML data so please forgive my ugly code.
Thanks for all help given!

**UPDATE**  
I was able to select a particular Document node by using the SelectNodes function Ann L provided below. I am still running into an issue to where the message box is only showing one instance of all fields listed in that box.

The Document I selected was 'Document Name 3'. The message box returned all 7 fields in one box. If possible I am wanting to display 7 different message boxes.

Here is the code I am using...   
**VB Code**

```
Dim sd As New XmlDocument()
    Dim sdXML As New FileStream("xmlFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim sdNode As XmlNodeList
    Dim sdNum As Integer
    Dim Field As Object

    sd.Load(sdXML)
    sdNode = sd.SelectNodes("descendant::DocType[Name='Document Name 3']")

    For sdNum = 0 To sdNode.Count - 1

        For Each Field In sdNode
            MsgBox(sdNode(sdNum).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText)
        Next

    Next
```

Comment: "I am also not able to get it to search by a particular node (Document)", mind to add an expected nodes sample given the XML above as input? And I agree with Ann's suggestion, `SelecteNodes`+xpath will help you a lot in getting any part of an XML document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sdNode` gives you the `DocType` node.  Its child nodes are the `Document` nodes (or `Name` nodes; your example XML is inconsistent).

So you need to go deeper, to `Fields` and `Field`.

I haven't done VB.NET in a while, so my syntax may be off, but this is approximately what you would need to do:

```
'  DocType\Document\Fields\Field'
For sdNum = 0 To sdNode.Count - 1
    fieldNode = sdNode(sdNum).GetElementsByTagName("Field")
    for fldNum = 0 to fieldNode.Count - 1
       sdMsg = fieldNode(fieldNum).InnerText
       MsgBox(sdMsg)
    Next
Next
```

I'm assuming you want to process the nodes by `DocType` or `Document` node; if you just want all the fields without regard for what their ancestors are, you could just do

```
fieldNode = sd.GetElementsByTagName("Field")
for fldNum = 0 to fieldNode.Count - 1
   sdMsg = fieldNode(fldNum).InnerText
   MsgBox(sdMsg)
Next
```

I am not sure what you mean by "where name equals".  Do you mean the tag name?  Or the value of the `Name` element?

If you want to fetch a node, using a complex condition (say, all the `Field` nodes belonging to a `Document` with `id` = 2) you should look at the [SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx) function, and at [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx).

**ADDITIONAL ANSWERS (added 4/27/2015):**

The reason you are seeing all your `Field` nodes' contents squished together is that you are asking for the `InnerText` property of the `Document` node (the first child of the `DocType` node that you have retrieved with the `XPath`.)  "InnerText" retrieves the inner text of *all* descendent nodes of the current node, and squishes it together.

To get the `Field` nodes one at a time, you're going to have to delve deeper into hierarchy.

Try this.  It was done from memory and not tested, but it's approximately what you need:

```
sd.Load(sdXML)
sdNode = sd.SelectNodes("descendant::DocType[Name='Document Name 3']")

For sdNum = 0 To sdNode.Count - 1  ' This is the DocType node'

    Dim Field as XmlNode
    For Each Field In sdNode(sdNum).SelectNodes("descendent::Field")
        MsgBox(Field.InnerText)
    Next

Next
```

Comment: @DataBox  I have added additional suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Your memory is pretty spot on! I just had to make one extra edit. The descendent:: was needing to be replaced with //.  Below is the code I used. 
`For Each Field In sdNode(sdNum).SelectNodes("//Field")`
 Thanks again!

Comment: To further narrow down the results I also used... 

`For Each Field In sdNode(sdNum).SelectNodes("//DocType[Name = 'Batch Sheets']/Fields/Field")`

Comment: @DataBox Great!  I'm glad my answer was helpful and that you're able to further refine it!